# Where I could find good explanation how Google App Engine python27 threads works and what are limitations?

Tags: multithreading, google-app-engine, python-2.7

Where is good information about **threads implementation in python27 on Google App Engine** especially but not only:

1. What is threading limitation (how many thread could be spawn, what is number of spawned threads).
2. How handlers is spawned in threading (how looks initialization of handler).
3. How to be thread safe on Google App Engine (what additional assumption is take in GAE).
4. How simulate thread in SDK?
5. All other important things need to be know but not asked/missed in these three points.

Please help with some information or links. I know threading but not understand implementation  in Google App Engine and want learned it and share with you.

Answer (score 1):

Checking out 'Getting the Most Out of Python 2.7 on App Engine' at #io12 #cloudplatform

https://developers.google.com/events/io/sessions/gooio2012/300/

Comment: You can also find other sessions here https://developers.google.com/events/io/sessions